# Discrete Time Markov Chain Problem

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

So I have been given following information:
I have two people sitting in two rooms. Let they be called R1 and R2. At a discrete steps of time, I pick an adult at random from either of the rooms and let it decide where to sit next- the chosen adult can decide to stay or move with equal probability. Let's consider a Markov chain with states denoting the number of adults sitting in R1. 
What is the transition probability matrix?

My attempt:
So let the states be {0,1,2}

I want to work on each transition probability matrix element separately.

P(00) = 0.5 (which means initially both of the adults were in R2, and the one I chose decided to stay in R2)
P(01) = 0.5 (the chosen one from R2 decided to move to R1)
P(02) = 0 (both of them cannot go to R1 together)

But I am confused about elements of the second row. Any hint on how to compute that?
I am confused because for example: P(10) means initially, the two adults were in separate room and then the chosen adult has to be from R1 and he decided to move to R2, so P(10) = 0.5, but what about P(11) and P(12).

Comment: In fact you have $$P(1,0) = 0.25, \quad P(1,1) = 0.5, \quad P(1,2) = 0.25.$$ In order to have the transition $1\to0$, you must pick the adult in the first room and let that guy move to the other room, and each step costs probability of 0.5 independently. Similar computation tells that $1\to2$ occurs with probability 0.25. For $1\to1$, you may simply ask whoever picked to stay in their current room.

Comment: I had similar thought for P(0,1) as well. First, I have to choose an adult(both are in R2 initially) and the chosen adult then decides to stay or move. To me, they seem two independent events. Why is the probability not equal to 0.25 in that case? 0.5 for choosing an adult and 0.5 for whether he decides to stay or move.

Comment: That is because we have two adults. To avoid confusion, let us name them by A1 and A2, respectively. Then what we do at each step is to perform one out of the following four possibilities $$ \{\text{A1 stays}\},\quad\{\text{A1 moves}\},\quad\{\text{A2 stays}\},\quad\{\text{A2 moves}\}$$with equal probability and examine the outcome. In the case of $0\to1$, there are two possibilites that lead to $0\to1$ and thus $P(0,1) = 2\times0.25=0.5$.